# A Single Word Does Not Belong : He Says

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Grandpa seemed to have spent some time writing something.

"What are you writing, Grandpa?", I asked.

"Just trying to tie up some ends here. Check it out", he says.

The (strange) sentence merely was

> **Ada, Ali, Ana, Dan, Dom, Gary, Mark, Stan and Tina had only one car in LA,CA,US.**

"So what?" I asked.

"Only a single word does not belong in that sentence. Nothing to do with grammar,son. Can you tell which one and why?"

"And son I left out a few names that could be easily added to that sentence. Which ones?"

I was stumped. Typical Grandpa. I couldn't. So he told me. Should have known. Everything he says can be a clue! There was a clear reason why he chose the names and words.

Can you guess?

Comment: are spaces intentionally left out between LA,CA,US? or does spaces matter?

Comment: No spaces do not matter. Only words. As you know it is city,state and Country,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The odd word out in the sentence is:

> **ONLY**

Because:

> All of the other words in the sentence (including the names) can be found at the **end of country names**. (This explains the relevance of Grandpa's statement: 'trying to tie up some *ends* here'...)

Like so:

> Ada = **Canada/Grenada**
>  Ali = **Mali**
>  Ana = **Botswana/Ghana/Guyana**
>  Dan = **Jordan/Sudan/South Sudan**
>  Dom = **United Kingdom**
>  Gary = **Hungary**
>  Mark = **Denmark**
>  Stan = **Afghanistan/Kazakhstan/Kyrgyzstan/Pakistan/Tajikistan/Turkmenistan/Uzbekistan**
>  and = **Finland/Iceland/Ireland/New Zealand/Poland/Switzerland/Thailand**
>  Tina =**Argentina**
>  had = **Chad**
>  only = **NO COUNTRIES END IN 'ONLY'**
>  one = **Sierra Leone**
>  car = **Madagascar**
>  in = **Bahrain/Benin/Liechtenstein/Spain**
>  LA = **Angola/Guatemala/Venezuela**
>  CA = **Costa Rica/Dominica/Jamaica/South Africa/United States of America**
>  US = **Belarus/Cyprus/Mauritius**

Other names that could have been valid for the sentence include:

> **Olivia** (Bolivia), **Salvador** (El Salvador), **Reece** (Greece), **Rocco** (Morocco) and **Erica** (United States of America) - although since these are substantially longer than those used in the puzzle, they may well have been a bigger giveaway!
>  <sub>*Note that there are also many other regular dictionary words that could have been used in the sentence like **So** (Burkina Faso), **Tan** (Bhutan), **Many/Any** (Germany) and **Ran** (Iran), to name just a few...)*</sub>

Comment: Correct  I meant to say Rocco

Comment: @DrD Ah yeah, that's another. I suspect there might be a few other niche ones or culturally-very-specific ones lurking in the list too, but I think I've found most of the more common ones...

Comment: Sia, Pan, Aly, Ina, Nam, Gal...

Comment: My point exactly! :)